# Complex Integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|\lambda t|}e^{itx}dt$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, complex-integration

I'm working through Big Rudin's (Real and Complex Analysis) Fourier Transform chapter, and the following complex integral is part of a discussion on the Inverse Transform that Rudin mentions briefly without resolving, and I'm very curious how this is done.

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|\lambda t|}e^{itx}dt$

What I remember from my Complex Analysis days, is to take the limit of the integral evaluated around a contour from -R to R, and then around $C_R$, the semicircle connecting -R and R. Since this is closed I can use the Cauchy Residue Theorem, and by Jordan's Lemma hopefully the integral around $C_R$ will vanish, so I'm left with

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|\lambda t|}e^{itx}dt=2\pi*\{\text{sum of residues}\}$

However, this integral has no residues, so simply taking the limit of this integral from -R to R should work, but my rusty integration techniques aren't helping and Mathematica is not giving me any results.

Any help in solving this is much appreciated!

Comment: Split the integral between $[-\infty,0[$ and $[0,+\infty[$.

Comment: Your function is not holomorphic so why are you talking about residues... this is just a real analysis exercise.

Comment: @mercio Thx for your comment, I'm editing it now that I see it better. I began asking this as a complex question because it is part of Rudin's Complex analysis section in a chapter on the Fourier Transform, and this integral is inside another integral that is complex, so I got carried away

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $F(x)$ be the function defined by the [Fourier Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions)

$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|\lambda t|}e^{itx}\,dt$$

Since the integral converges for $\lambda \ne 0$, we can write the integral as

$$F(x)=\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{-R}^R e^{-|\lambda t|}e^{itx}\,dt$$

One might be tempted to evaluate this integral be closing the real line contour with a semi-circle, centered at the origin and with radius $R$, in the upper-half or lower-half plane and then using the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).  However, this approach is fatally flawed since $e^{-|\lambda||z|}$ is not an [Analytic Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function).  Therefore, we proceed along a different way forward.

First, we use [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) and exploit even and odd components of the integrand to reveal

$$F(x)=2\int_0^\infty e^{-|\lambda|t}\cos (xt)\,dt$$

Then, [Integrating by Parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) twice yields

$$\begin{align}
F(x)&=\lim_{R\to \infty}\left.\left(\frac{e^{-|\lambda|t}\left(-|\lambda|\cos (xt)+x\sin(x t)\right)}{x^2+|\lambda|^2}\right)\right|_{t=0}^{t=R}\\\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{|\lambda|}{x^2+|\lambda|^2}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: thanks a lot, this is really insightful. I've never used Euler's Identity I'll read up on it!

Comment: ...which yields a delta distributionin the limit $\delta \rightarrow 0$. This is one (not totally rigorous) way to prove that the FT of 1 is the delta distribution.

Comment: @tired Excellent Point.  The result is one regularized form for the Dirac Delta.  Does Rudin's Book discuss tempered distributions?

Comment: @Craig You're quite welcome.  My pleasure.  I'll add a link to the post on Euler's Identity.

Comment: @Dr.MV I haven't come across tempered distributions. The Dirac Delta is discussed later on. However, I do see that Rudin mentions that the solution to this integral is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}*\frac{|\lambda|}{x^2+|\lambda|}$

This question I asked because Rudin evaluates $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|\lambda t|}e^{itx}dt)dx=1$ So I'm also trying to figure out if the outer integral comes out equal to 1!

So I'm trying to figure out where that extra factor comes from.

Comment: different convention of fourier transform i guess

Comment: @Craig There are various ways to define the FT.  The symmetrical form has factors of $\sqrt{2/\pi}$ on both the forward and inverse transforms.

Comment: @Dr.MV I see, thanks a bunch, I'll ask the last step in this integration in a new question.

Comment: @Craig By last step, do you mean [Integration by Parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts)?

Comment: @Dr.MV I mean I asked this because Rudin evaluates this: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|\lambda t|}e^{itx}dt)dx=1$

And now that you figured the inside integral I'm trying to calculate the outside one to yield 1, but I get $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{|\lambda|}{x^2+|\lambda|}dx= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\pi\not=1$

Comment: @Craig Rudin consistently uses $dm(x)$ in that chapter, where _in that chapter_ $dm$ denotes Lebesgue measure divided by $\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Comment: @Dr.MV You have somewhere lost a factor $2$, the correct result is $\frac{2\lvert \lambda\rvert}{x^2 + \lvert\lambda\rvert^2}$.

Comment: @Craig And hence one obtains $h_{\lambda}(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\cdot \frac{\lvert \lambda\rvert}{x^2 + \lvert\lambda\rvert^2}$, which nicely yields $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} h_{\lambda}(x)\, dm(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} h_{\lambda}(x)\,dx = 1.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks a lot, this clears it up! I'll try to go through Dr.MV's answer and see here that factor is supposed to come from.

A few pages in the text I forgot Rudin mentioned he will incorporate the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$ in the dmx of the integral.

Answer (score 0):

Use is made of even function and Laplace transform:
\begin{align}
F(x)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|\lambda t|}e^{itx}\,dt\\
&\overset{s=|\lambda|}=2\int_{0}^\infty e^{-s t}\cos(tx)\,dt\\
&=\frac{2s}{s^2+x^2}.
\end{align}